# Trying to understand Infinite Conditional white loop

Tags: python

I have the loop below which is a conditional `while` and I am just wondering how come it ends up being an Infinite loop.

```
count = 0            
while count!=12 or count!=6: 
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: `count` can't have 2 values at once.

Comment: use `and` instead of or

Comment: Well, when count is 6, it is not 12. And when it is 12, it is not 6. :/.

Comment: The words "and" and "or" make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `or` to `and`, as written your condition is always `True`.

```
while count != 12 and count != 6:
```

`count` cannot simultaneously be `12` and `6`, so one of those expressions will always be True.

This expression can be explained using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

[image]

In Python this would be

```
not (p or q) == (not p) and (not q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other ones mentioned you need `and` instead of `or`.

The reason is when your loop is counting up you'll get the following:

```
1 != 6 or 12
2 != 6 or 12
...
6 == 6 but != 12 # keeps going
7 != 6 or 12
...
12 != 6 but == 12 # keeps going
...
# infinite loop.
```